# save date-picker date in access database

Tags: c#, wpf, date

when i try to save a date from a date-picker into an access database, its only saving the time. so it only shows 12:00:21AM but i want it to only show the mm/dd/yyy
How do i do this. There are the things i have tried.

```
datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

and

```
datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

but both these are just returning a time, and not the date.
Please help me figure this out, i would gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer by trial and error.

```
var invoiceDate = datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

and stuck the invoiceDate into my insert into query. for some reason this worked, and the other didnt. dont quite understand why, so if anyone has any input on this, please feel free to expand on this.